# Comma as letter and semicolon as operator in math formulas

Tags: tex-core, punctuation, mathcode

Inside document `source2e.pdf` there are the following two lines

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{letters}{"3B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{;}{\mathpunct}{operators}{"3B}
```

which treats these two punctuation symbols differently: comma as letter while semicolon as operator.

I know that the above code will assign different `mathcode` to these two punctuation symbols

```
\mathcode`\,="613B
\mathcode`\;="603B
```

and therefore they will be typeset in different fonts (`cmmi` and `cmr` by default).

Is there any reason why TeX treat these two punctuation symbols differently?

Answer (score 1):

There's no semicolon in the OML encoding, so it cannot be taken from the default `letters` font. Space is crucial to understanding why TeX takes things from certain places: only 128 places per font. If you think it should come from `cmmi`, ask what should be taken out to free up a slot?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: But why not remove comma from `cmmi` font, and take both comma and semicolon from `cmr` font? (i.e., why Knuth still put comma into `cmmi` font despite of the limited places?)